# "Good" States In Degenerate Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

During the section on Degenerate Perturbation Theory, Griffiths (Introduction to Quantum Mechanics 2ed) starts with a general linear combination of two orthogonal eigenfunctions of $H_0$. He walks through a derivation of the energy of the perturbed states (including the lifting of the degeneracies. He shows that if we set $\alpha$ to $0$, we get the same result we would have gotten in non-degenerate perturbation theory, and similarly for $\beta$. The rest of the section seems to be about finding the "good" eigenstates. What I don't understand is : what's special about $\psi_a$ and $\psi_b$? The only conditions we imposed on them is that they are mutually degenerate and that they are orthogonal eigenfunctions of $H_0$. Shouldn't we be able to apply non-degenerate perturbation theory the way described for any two orthogonal, degenerate eigenfunctions of $H_0$? (i.e. any orthogonal basis formed in the span of $\psi_a$ and $\psi_b$) [Griffiths Chp 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CiWn.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I remember hating that section of Griffiths; seemed so algebraic. Later, I learned that $E_\pm^1$ was related to the determinant of a matrix, which you can see if you look carefully at the expression, and which Griffiths doesn't make as apparent as it ought to be IMO. See a more advanced textbook (like Sakurai IIRC) for more info.

Comment: I answered an extremely similar question here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119837/why-are-the-zeroth-order-terms-in-degenerate-perturbation-theory-the-eigenstates. As such, I think this is probably a duplicate (but I don't know how to vote for that).

Comment: I think I understand now. So we're looking for eigenfunctions for $H^1$ ? My issue currently is that the only constraints we placed on $\psi^0_a$ and $\psi^0_b$ are that they are mutually degenerate with respect to $H^0$ and that they are mutually orthogonal. Wouldn't we obtain the same result if we were to  define $\psi^1 = \alpha_1\psi^0_a + \beta_1\psi^0_b$ and $\psi^2 = \alpha_2\psi^0_a + \beta_2\psi^0_b$ where $\psi^1$ and $\psi^2$ are mutually orthogonal?

Comment: @ZaneDufour: Did you read the question and answer linked in my previous comment? Your question is answered there.

Comment: @DanielSank I still don't quite understand. We choose the unperturbed states to be eigenfunctions of $H^0$ (obviously). But since we have (in this case) a two-fold degeneracy, we have to choose a linear combination of two orthonormal, degenerate (under $H^0$) states $\psi^0_a$ and $\psi^0_b$. $\psi^0 = \alpha\psi^0_a + \beta\psi^0)b$ But we see in 6.22 and 6.24 (in op) that if $\alpha = 0$ then $E_1 = W_(bb)$ which is the fundamental result of nondegenerate perturbation theory. Don't the states $\psi^0_a$ and $\psi^0_b$ serve as "good" states, since we haven't specified a specific $H^1$?

Comment: i think this question should be opened again.