# Confusion about the first-order correction term of an eigenstate (Degenerate Perturbation Theory)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

I'll try my best to put into words what I want to know. But I have the feeling that it is hard to properly explain and correctly articulate the different notations and formulas for this particular topic.

Let's have an unperturbed system and it's unperturbed Hamiltonian ($H_0$) has eigenvalues, some of them may be degenerate, i.e arbitrary eigenvalue $E_n^{(0)}$ is $g_n$ times degenerated. The eigenvectors that belong to this degenerate eigenvalue, span the Eigenspace and are of the form: $|n^k\rangle_{0}$

We now introduce a disturbance $\lambda W$ and the Hamiltonian is perturbed ($H=H_0+\lambda W$). The expression for a perturbed eigenstate, that corresponds to one of the degenerated unperturbed eigenstates of the initial system,is: $|n^k\rangle=|n^k\rangle_0+\lambda|n^k\rangle_1+...$.

Now I know that the first order correction term: $|n^k\rangle_1$ has two parts contributing to it: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/33e9de64d8622d6b7c714723f58801a094d4de01

One that comes from all the unperturbed eigenvectors which do not belong to the eigenspace, where the unperturbed degenerate eigenstate ($|n^k\rangle_{0}$) (which in the perturbed system is the eigenstate $|n^k\rangle$, for which we are trying to find the first order correction term) belongs, and one term that comes from considering the unperturbed degenerate eigenvectors of the eigenspace, to where the unperturbed eigenvector $|n^k\rangle_{0}$ belongs.

Before I ask my **one and only** question, I will show an example, because my question is a result of this example combined with the above mentioned theory:

I had an example where we had a 2D quantum harmonic oscillator. For simplicity we considered the first energy eigenvalue, which is two-fold degenerate. Now in the Eigenraum of this eigenvalue, we derived how the matrix of the disturbance operator $W$ looks like. It is a 2x2 matrix and it wasn't diagonal. Then we diagonalize this and find the corresponding eigenvalues, which could be expressed as the linear combination of the basis kets of the Eigenspace, in other words of the $g_n$ (2 here) degenerate unperturbed eigenvectors. Since this is a basic example, I am pretty confident that it is understood what I am saying. We can then replace the unperturbed degenerate eigenvalues $|n^k\rangle_{0}$ of $H_0$ with these eigenvalues, for which the disturbance operator is diagonal. $H_0$ would still be diagonal in the Hilbert space spanned by it's eigenvectors, but where those that are degenerate to $E_n^{(0)}$ are substituted with those, for which $W$ is diagonal.

**Now my question is THIS**:

Do we, in the expression  for finding the first correction term $|n^k\rangle_1$ of the perturbed eigenstate $|n^k\rangle$, that corresponds to a degenerated unperturbed eigenstates $|n^k\rangle_{0}$ of the initial system, in the part of it that is related to the Eigenspace, where it's unperturbed counterpart belongs, instead of using the "old" unperturbed degenerate eigenvectors ($|n^k\rangle_{(0)}$ k=1...$g_n$), we use those, that we find after diagonalizing the matrix which represents the disturbance operator in the eigenspace?

Because if not then what good are these eigenvectors, one finds when diagonalizing the disturbance operator in the eigenspace, other then making the disturbance operator a diagonal matrix in it?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119837/

Comment: It doesn't really give an explanation as to what we do with the eigenvectors that we find as a result of diagonalizing the disturbance matrix in the Eigenspace of a degenerate value. The only thing I can think of, is that we use this new eigenvectors, when we try to find the first order correction term of the Energy. But for this I need confirmation

Comment: Correct; for example, see the equation $E_n'=\langle \bar\varphi_n | \hat{H}'|\bar\varphi_n\rangle, \ (n\leq q)$ where $E_n'$ is the first order correction to the $n$-th energy level (which has $q$-fold degeneracy), $\hat{H}'$ is the perturbation Hamiltonian, and $\bar\varphi_n$ are linear combinations of eigenvectors of the free Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_0$ that diagonalize $\hat{H}'$ on the degenerate subspace of $\hat{H}_0$. More details can be found here: http://physics.gmu.edu/~dmaria/590%20Web%20Page/public_html/qm_topics/degenerate/index.html#x1-80001.6

Comment: "...are linear combinations of eigenvectors of the free Hamiltonian.." of the unperturbed degenerate eigenvectors, for the degenereate counterpart of them we are trying to find the first order corrections,right? This is what "eigenvectors of the free hamiltonian" means. Because the free hamiltonian has many states, but we are focused in a set of degenerate ones, right?

Comment: One additional thing, which is not showcased in the link you provided (thank you btw), do we use these new eigenvectors, when finding first and 2nd order correction terms for the eigenstates, regardless whether these are degenerated or not?

Comment: For your first comment -- yes, that's what I meant when I said "$\bar\varphi_n$ are linear combinations of eigenvectors of the free Hamiltonian $H_0$ **that diagonalize $H'$ on the degenerate subspace of $\hat{H}_0$**."

Comment: For your second comment, also yes -- once you know the "good" states $\bar{\varphi}_n$, you just use these as you would any other state in regular, non-degenerate perturbation theory, in computing corrections to energy levels or eigenstates at any order.